# Помогите мне нужно в словах в которых больше 2 буквы «о» чтоб непринтовало

Tags: ios, swift

```
  let text = "Ця строкао нічого не значить, але Суть в томоу щобо навчитись працювати З строками, і стати іOC Девелоперомоо"
              var testArray: [String] = []
              var word = ""
              var counterChrO = 0
              
        for char in text {
            if char != " " {
                if char.lowercased() == "о" {
                    counterChrO += 1
                  
                }
                word.append(char)
                    
            } else {
                if counterChrO < 2 {
                    testArray.append(word)
                }
      counterChrO = 0
                word = ""
            }
            
        }
        print(testArray)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот метод, который это делает. Сначала идет разделение на слова, потом в каждом слове перебираются буквы и при этом считается количество букв "о". Потом, если букв "о" меньше 2, слово добавляется в результирующий массив. В завершении массив конвертируется обратно в строку и возвращается наружу метода. Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте :)

```
func removeDoubleO(text: String) -> String {
  let splittedArray = text.split(separator: " ")
  var resultArray: [String] = []

  for word in splittedArray {
    var counter = 0
    for char in word {
      if char.lowercased() == "о" {
        counter += 1
      }
    }
    if counter < 2 {
      resultArray.append(String(word))
    }
  }

  return resultArray.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

В вашем коде в первом цикле зачем-то из строки удаляются пробелы и она становится одним большим словом. Потом вы проверяете в этом "слове" что там меньше двух букв "о". Естественно во всем предложении без пробелов их будет больше 2. Поэтому и не работает. Кроме всего этого, есть ошибки при "стыковке" разных типов данных и еще вы заранее не объявляете массивы и переменные (например ваш счетчик count).

Добавил измененный вариант ответа: метод просто распечатывает отдельные слова, исключая содержащие две буквы "о", то есть как Вам и нужно:

```
func removeDoubleO(text: String) {
  let splittedArray = text.split(separator: " ")
  for word in splittedArray {
    var counter = 0
    for char in word {
      if char.lowercased() == "о" {
        counter += 1
      }
    }
    if counter < 2 {
      print(word)
    }
  }
}
```

Добавляю код после вашего исправления. Мой метод версии 3.0 :) Теперь он возвращает массив, как Вам и нужно.

```
func removeDoubleO(text: String) -> [String] {
  let splittedArray = text.split(separator: " ")
  var resultArray: [String] = []
  for word in splittedArray {
    var counter = 0
    for char in word {
      if char.lowercased() == "о" {
        counter += 1
      }
    }
    if counter < 2 {
      resultArray.append(String(word))
    }
  }
  return resultArray
}
```

Вот результат работы метода при обработке Вашего текста (скриншот из консоли):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видите, слов с двумя "о" в массиве нет.

Comment: Мне нужно записать это предложение в массив слов и пройтись циклов по предложению и не принтовать слова в которых больше 2 букв "о". Выше я записал предложение в массив, а сейчас нужно пройтись циклом и непринтовать слова в которых больше двух букв "о", но у меня не получается.

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать вопрос, так чтобы там был весь код? Потому что то что там написано, работать не будет. Хочу посмотреть, что будет выводить print в вашем случае. Непонятен тип данных для word и testArray.

Comment: И ещё, мой метод делает всё то, что вы хотите, только еще в конце объединяет слова обратно в предложение. Его конечно можно и упростить, чтобы просто распечатал отдельные слова. Так будет еще проще и короче.

Comment: Я отредактировал посмотрите. Должно быть так, только без слов где есть две буквы "о".

Comment: Так а ваш код из вопроса, он как-то работает? Что-то выдает вообще? Вы его запускали? Просто он сейчас в нерабочем виде, я это имел ввиду.

Comment: Добавил третий вариант кода в свой ответ. Теперь он выдает массив слов, как у вас в вопросе, после исправления. У вас теперь целых три варианта одного и того же метода (как видите, там особо ничего не меняется), которые выдают результат в виде 1. Строки слов. 2. Принта слов в консоль 3. Массива слов.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Так получилось или нет?

Comment: да, но я зделал ишо другим способом:) Спасибо вам:)

Comment: Понятно, это хорошо :) Напишите сам себе ответ. Пусть и другие знают разные способы. Если хотите конечно.

Comment: испавил, посмотрите:)

Comment: уменя квам другой вопрос:)

Comment: Если Вы хотите показать вариант верного кода, то не стоит тогда его менять в самом теле вопроса. Достаточно лишь создать новый ответ с указанием того, что Вы сделали для решения вопроса

Comment: Спрашивайте, или новый вопрос в стековерфлоу задавайте )